# How to @click change the data in the array with Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have a table with two-button **Inch** and **CM**, and I want to change the numbers from Inch to CM on click, Please can someone teach me how to do it

[image]

```js
 data() {
        return {

          guild_size_inch: [
            {
              size: "S",
              chest: "92",
              length: "71"
            },
            {
              size: "M",
              chest: "40",
              length: "29"
            },
            {
              size: "L",
              chest: "44",
              length: "30"
            }
          ],
        }
      },
  
      methods: {
        changeToCM: function() {
          this.guild_size_inch * 2.54;
          alert(this.guild_size_inch)
        }
      }
```

Comment: I added an answer, Hope that will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a below code snippet as per your requirement. Please find the explanation of the logic inline in the snippet.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      guild_size_inch: [
        {
          size: "S",
          chest: "92",
          length: "71"
        },
        {
          size: "M",
          chest: "40",
          length: "29"
        },
        {
          size: "L",
          chest: "44",
          length: "30"
        }
      ],
      isInch: true, // property to enable/disable the 'Inch' button.
      isCM: false // property to enable/disable the 'CM' button.
    }
  },
  methods: {
    // Method used to convert the Inch values into CM.
    changeToCM() {
      this.isCM = true;
      this.isInch = false;
      this.guild_size_inch = this.guild_size_inch.map((obj) => {
        obj.chest = parseInt(obj.chest) * 2.54;
        obj.length = parseInt(obj.length) * 2.54;
        return obj;
      });
    },
    // Method used to convert the CM values into Inch.
    changeToInch() {
        this.isCM = false;
      this.isInch = true;
      this.guild_size_inch = this.guild_size_inch.map((obj) => {
        obj.chest = Math.ceil(parseInt(obj.chest) / 2.54);
        obj.length = Math.ceil(parseInt(obj.length) / 2.54);
        return obj;
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="changeToInch" :disabled="isInch">Inch (Default)</button>
  <button @click="changeToCM" :disabled="isCM">CM</button>
  <table>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Chest</th>
    <th>Length</th>
    <tr v-for="(item, index) in guild_size_inch" :key="index">
      <td>{{ item.size }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.chest }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.length }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to multiply the object instead of the numbers contains in your object.

What you should try is loop through your array and multiply both chest and length.

You can perform this with a `forEach` loop : [see documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
changeToCM: function() {
   this.guild_size_inch.forEach(item => {
      item.chest = parseInt(item.chest) * 2.54
      item.length = parseInt(item.length) * 2.54
   });
   alert(this.guild_size_inch)
}
```

Comment: I see, I really appreciate it, that's teaching me a lot, I have another question, how to get back to Inch again? or I should make same function and change the formula?

Comment: I think there are 3 ways of doing this : Either you can make another method `changeToInch`, pass a parameter to the existing function or set a global parameter like @Boussadjra Brahim suggests and check it in the existing function

Answer (score 1):

Define a property called `currentUnit` initially set to `inch` which will be changes by the click event, then use a computed property that returns the sizes based on the current unit which you selected :

```js
 data() {
   return {
      guild_size_inch:[....],
      currentUnit:'cm'

   }
 },
computed:{
   sizes(){
      return this.guild_size_inch.map(size=>{
          size.chest=this.currentUnit==='cm'?size.chest*2.54:size.chest*2.54
          size.length=this.currentUnit==='cm'?size.length/2.54:size.length/2.54
         return size;
    })
  }
},
methods:{
  changeUnit() {
     this.currentUnit==='cm'?this.currentUnit='inch':this.currentUnit='cm'
 }
}
```

then render the `sizes` in the table.

Comment: that's genius, thank you so much for this amazing code and explanation, I do have a few questions, to switch between Inch and Cm need to add @click="currentUnit = 'inch'"?
the second question is when I added Math.ceil() the numbers increasing when I switch to inch to cm or cm to inch:

size.chest=this.currentUnit==='cm'?Math.ceil(size.chest*2.54):Math.ceil(size.chest/2.54)
size.length=this.currentUnit==='cm'?Math.ceil(size.length*2.54):Math.ceil(size.length/2.54)

Comment: you should add `@click="changeUnit"`  please look at the edited answer I fixed some mistakes